# JSession variable does not get set when including component in article

Tags: php, joomla

I've got a Joomla component for which I'm attempting to add some functionality. I've found that if I call the component directly via `http://mysite.com/index.php?option=com_mycom&view=unsubscribe` the form submits just fine.

However, if I include the component in an article with `{component url='index.php?option=com_mycom&view=unsubscribe'}` to get the page to simply be `http://mysite.com/unsubscribe` the token does not appear to get stored properly and I will get the error message about 'invalid or expired token' with either a blank `$stored_token` value, or the value from when the page was last loaded via the long, direct URL.

How can I remedy this behaviour?

```
$confirm = JRequest::getVar('unsubscribe_confirm', NULL);
$sess = JFactory::getSession();
if( is_null($confirm) ) {
    // generate random token to prevent accident/malicious use
    $token = md5(rand().time().$sub_info['id_joomla_user']);
    $sess->set('unsubscribe_token', $token, 'mycom_unsubscribe');
    $frm = <<<_E_
<form action="%sindex.php?option=com_mycom&view=unsubscribe" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="unsubscribe_token" value="%s" />
    <input type="submit" name="unsubscribe_confirm" value="Yes, please cancel my subscription." />
</form>
_E_;
    $output = sprintf(JURI::root(), $token);
} else {
    $token_stored = $sess->get('unsubscribe_token', NULL, 'mycom_unsubscribe');
    $token_passed = JRequest::getVar('unsubscribe_token', NULL);
    // make sure tokens have been set, and that they match
    if( (is_null($token_stored) || is_null($token_passed)) || ($token_stored !== $token_passed) ) {
        JFactory::getApplication()->redirect(
            'profile',
            'Cannot process unsubscribe request: expired or invalid session token.' .
            ' S:' . $token_stored . ' P:' . $token_passed,
            'error'
        );
    } else {
        // valid unsubscribe request has been given, unset token to prevent multiple requests.
        $sess->clear('unsubscribe_token', 'mycom_unsubscribe');
        // more code normally happens here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that including components with curly braces is not a built-in Joomla feature like I had thought, but a plugin called 'Include Component'. Which fires of a cURL request internally to get the component content and royally screwing with anything that requires session validation.

Answer (score 0):

A component should already have a view which you can link from the Menu manager. If you need to change the way things look, check the template overrides.